# Can you help me in this error? AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, feature-extraction, feature-selection

in 
`all_features = X_train.keys()`

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'

This my code:

````
    cor_list = []

    #calculate the correlation with y for each feature
    for i in all_features:
        cor = np.corrcoef(X_train[i], y_train, rowvar=False)[0, 1]
        cor_list.append(cor)
     #replace NaN with 0
    cor_list = [0 if np.isnan(i) else i for i in cor_list]
    #feature_name
    cor_feature = X_train.iloc[:np.argsort(np.abs(cor_list))[-num_feats:]].columns.tolist()
    #feature selection? 0 for not select, 1 for select
    cor_support = [True if i in cor_feature else False for i in all_features]
    X_train_selected = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=cor_feature)
    X_test_selected = pd.DataFrame(X_test, column = cor_feature)
    # Correlation with output variable
    return X_train_selected, X_test_selected


**This when i called in main:**

``` all_features = X_train.keys()

X_train_selected, X_test_selected = FS.Feature_cor_selector(X_train, X_test, y_train, 10, all_features) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

ndarray does not have a "keys" attribute. You can find the documentation, and all of the attributes, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#. You should probably use X_train.flags()

Comment: I use `X_train.flags()` , but another error appear : TypeError: 'numpy.flagsobj' object is not callable

Comment: Sorry, it's not a function, it's just X_train.flags